# How far can 3.3V UART go at 38400 baud?

Tags: serial, uart, communication

I'm developing a [set of boards](https://github.com/willemcvu/midi-solenoid-driver/) that will all be listening to a single 3.3V 38400 baud UART (single TX device, my boards all listen to this line, no "RX" line). They are designed such that there are two RJ12 jacks per-board, and the signal and ground is just passed between the RJ12, with the signal going to the uC on each board. The idea is to daisy chain up to max 5 of these boards, with less than a foot of cable between boards.

[image: multiple boards strung together]

Here's what the signal looks like after 1x 6" cable, a board, and another 6" cable.

[image: oscope1]
[image: oscope2]

How far can I reasonably expect this setup to work? I'm considering scrapping the whole thing and using RS-422 or RS-485 drivers, but that feels silly when these boards will have a 6" cable between them.

On a broader scale, how do you predict usable cable length given a baud rate and voltage level?

Comment: wait, is this a multi-tap bus (i.e. all µC inputs are electrically parallel) or is this a daisy-chain design where the first µC gets a signal on RX, and repeats it on its TX, which connects to the second µC's RX, and so on?

Comment: This is a multi-tap bus.

Comment: hm, might be interesting to see how much of the signal is swallowed by capacitive loading. You don't happen to have an oscilloscope?

Comment: by the way, these output transistors look *beefy*; nice thing!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, I do. Let me take a screenshot real fast...

Comment: Also just a note: I have 330 ohm resistors from the bus to the uC RX pin - these will likely actually be 0 ohm, I just wanted to put the footprint there for flexibility/I might put a low-value resistor there.

Comment: If you can tolerate some delay between boards, how about a "repeater" on each board, such that the signal will never degrade no matter how many boards are connected? Can also consider a beefy line-driver IC.

Comment: @willem.hill the resistors do make a lot of sense once you go high enough in rates; good idea to have them. Now, the scope picture looks extremely good.

Comment: Wait, you are sending one 0 to 3.3V signal to up to 5  destinations?  And the furthest one may be up to 5 feet away?  I doubt any micro processor output pin is designed to have a [fan-out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan-out) that high. This may work.  Then again it may not.  Maybe your application is in a noisy environment.  Or the power supply is not robust enough to filter out noise.  There are reasons for serial protocols like RS485 that use balanced twisted pair cables and support multiple drops.  And I think you should consider such communications to mitigate possible noise problems.

Comment: I wouldn't use plain single ended TTL UART over cables. Soon there will be new guy or customer that without much thought just lengthens your 6" cables, because they are standard cables, and it won't work reliably anymore.

Comment: Uh what a nice organ valve driver, great project, what is the latency you managed to have? I believe the real issue could be GND shift due to output current flowing on ground connections among boards. Noise margin on a single ended 3.3V databus is rather poor, if I were in your shoes I'd definitely go for a 485 transceiver on each board.

Answer (score 3):

To find the distance a signal can go the physical layer of communications needs to be specified.  [RS-422](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-422) & [RS-485](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485) define a physical layer that can be "looked up".  Descriptions such as UART do not define a physical layer and so are difficult to "lookup up" or comment on.

The cable used for long communications connections can play an important part in delivering a strong signal while mitigating the effects of electrical noise.  [Registered Jacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack) sometimes use twisted pair cables to accomplish this.  But specifying an [RJ12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack#RJ12) Registered Jack does not ensure this type of cable is used.

There are several other concerns when dealing with communications over cables.  [Ground Loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_loop_(electricity)) being among them.  In extreme cases [optical isolators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opto-isolator) are used to mitigate the effects of Ground Loops.

For this particular case, 0 to 3.3 V swing at 38400 baud over a 6 inch cable, it can only be said that it is a bit surprising that it does not work.  Consider the wiring is faulty or the signal is logically inverted. Then consider that the protocols at both ends do not match (such as parity, number of bits & length of stop).  Finally consider the speed it too great for the hardware or software to handle.

> On a broader scale, how do you predict usable cable length given a
>   baud rate and voltage level?

It would be difficult. Many other factors affect the signal such as line, source and termination impedance.  Inspecting the signal with an oscilloscope at the source and destination may give some insight.

Comment: Sorry to not be clear... The cables are 6 inches, but the signal is also getting passed through a 6" long PCB from the RJ12 jack on one side to the RJ12 jack on the other side. Here's a render of the exact project I'm working on: https://github.com/willemcvu/midi-solenoid-driver/raw/master/hardware/multiple-boards.PNG

Comment: It works, I just would like to theorize how much distance I could get with the current setup safely.

Comment: Do you have common grounds?

Comment: @MadHatter Yes, the grounds are guaranteed to be common.

Answer (score 1):

With actual RS-232 buffering a simple daisychain connection should work just fine at that baud rate. The limits cited for RS-232 are typically 50 feet or a max cable capacitance of 2500pF for rates up to 20kbit/s. Longer distances or higher rates are possible with low-capacitance cables.

Now, with the 3.3V TTY link you're proposing? Not so much. The noise margin of such an approach is suspect at best; you have multiple boards to deal with so ground loop issues can be a problem. If you insist, you should consider rebuffering the signal.

Your intuition to use RS-485 is a good one. It would solve those problems and help future-proof your design. RS-485 avoids a number of issues that RS-232 has, such as noise immunity and more-limited speed at distance. Since you’re already using RJ12 you have enough pins, so might as well go with that. And it can share the 3.3V supply with the rest of your logic.

Oh, and you can choose RS-485 that doesn't load the line down if the module power is off. This isn't so straightforward with logic-level interfacing, though it can be done.

---

**Going Further**

There is a popular protocol used for theatrical lighting called DMX512, that functions exactly the same as what you’re building. It’s a multi drop serial line, and each client is addressable. DMX512 uses RS-485, with up to 64 clients per loop and up to 400m in length running at 250 kbit/s.

More about DMX512 here: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/introduction-to-dmx/all

At the risk of killing your enthusiasm, are you possibly reinventing the wheel with your MIDI-to-solenoid idea?

MIDI to DMX: https://www.instructables.com/id/MIDI2DMX/

DMX solenoid driver: [https://www.amazon.com/Switch-Dmx512-Controller-Output-Control/dp/B00S9KABRA/ref=asc_df_B00S9KABRA/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00S9KABRA)

Answer (score 0):

Electricity travels 1 nanosecond per foot (+-).  40,000 BAUD system has 25,000 nanoseconds per baud, or 5 miles. At twisted-pair (SWAG) of 30 picoFarad/foot, the buss drivers need to handle? the TwistedPair impedance of about 100 ohms, or 50 milliAmps for 5 volt bus levels.

If you get reflections, then all bets are off.

To avoid problems with reflections, have slow rise/fall times, perhaps 10% of the baud time, and let the reflected energy get absorbed during the edge times. That limits you to 0.5 miles.